# How to receive a pulse in Javascript Sinch SDK call to PSTN

Tags: sinch, dtmf

I can see in the JS reference how to send a dial tone, but how can I process an incoming one in the JS SDK?
In other words, I need the call receiver to be able to press a number in their phone to acknowledge something and trigger an action in JS

Comment: have a look at [PROMPT INPUT EVENT CALLBACK (PIE)](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#PIE)

Answer (score 1):

DTMF is not for the other end JS client to recieve, its for the rest api to react on, think IVR etc

See @Redaniums (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339316/redanium) comment above https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#PIE

Comment: I want to receive a DTMF as part of a voice conversation. not when presented with a menu. So both people are actually talking and one of them presses a number to accept a request